# PHP function ssh2_connect is not working

Tags: php, ssh

Following is my script:

```
    <?php
    $connection = ssh2_connect('XX.XX.XX.XX', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', '******');

    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'useradd -d /home/users/test -m testftp');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'passwd testftp');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'password');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'password');
    ?>
```

It showing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /home/chaosnz/public_html/fotosnap.net/test.php on line 2
```

How can I deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you made sure that [the SSH2 PECL extension](http://php.net/book.ssh2) is installed and enabled?  It is *not* a part of standard PHP.

Comment: i have installed the SSH2 PECL extension and it working fine thanks all for you help..

Comment: When you can, you should post that as your answer and mark it accepted.  You might need to wait a bit before the system will let you do it.  This action will help future users with the same problem.

Comment: Any reason for down voted :(

Comment: While I was not one of the downvoters, I encourage you to hover over the downarrow and read the description given.  This answer doesn't really show a lot of research effort, so that's probably why others decided to downvote you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a shell command through ssh using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373632/execute-a-shell-command-through-ssh-using-php)

Comment: Try to see the answers on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373632/execute-a-shell-command-through-ssh-using-php/41572063#41572063

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have installed the SSH2 PECL extension and its working fine thanks all for you help...

Comment: How did you install that ?

Comment: with this http://programster.blogspot.ch/2013/06/centos-64-install-ssh2-extension-for-php.html

Answer (score 31):

Honestly, I'd recommend using phpseclib, a [pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

It's a ton more portable, easier to use and more feature packed too.

Comment: Could be a good solution for some people but I need something to work without any additional installations.

Comment: libssh2 requires libssh2 be installed. phpseclib just requires the files be somewhere on the filesystem but if you want to consider that to be an installation...  well, then, I guess the only real alternative left to you is to write your own SSH implementation. good luck with that.

Comment: Why tell someone to use a different lib when they are asking how to make the one they're using work?

Comment: @j_allen_morris - if someone is wanting to get `ereg` working in their project would you tell them to write a shim or would you tell them to use replace their `ereg` function call with the more modern `preg_match`? I'd say both "perspectives" are valid. Also, keep in mind that 23 people other than myself thought that this was a good / relevant enough answer to justify an up vote (as of this moment this answer has 23 up votes and 3 down votes). Certainly you're free to disagree.

Comment: @neubert "write your own SSH implementation" really? PHP has built-in functions to make ssh or sftp connection.

Comment: PHPSECLIB is underrated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 18):

I have solved this on ubuntu 16.4 PHP 7.0.27-0+deb9u and nginx

```
sudo apt install php-ssh2
```

Comment: This solved the error `Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()`  on Ubuntu 20.04LTS with PHP7.4 as well

Answer (score 13):

You need to install [ssh2 lib](http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php)

`sudo apt-get install libssh2-php && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

that should be enough to get you on the road

Comment: `Package libssh2-php is not available, but is referred to by another package.` How to solve this?

Comment: By usign the alternative suggested, `sudo apt-get install php-ssh2`

Answer (score 8):

If you are running a bomebrew on OSX, I used the following to install it:

```
brew install php56-ssh2
```

That worked for me.  I pulled it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050231/php-function-ssh2-connect-is-not-working).  There should also be Ubuntu and OSX using mac port as well.

Comment: After installed it, I still get `Call to undefined function App\ssh2_connect()` - Do you know why ?

Answer (score 3):

I am running CentOS 5.6 as my development environment and the following worked for me.

```
su -
pecl install ssh2
echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /etc/php.d/ssh2.ini

/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @neubert answer, if you are using Laravel 5 or similar, you can use phpseclib much simpler like this:

Run `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib ~2.0`

In your controller add

`use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;`

Then use it in a controller method like:

```
 $host = config('ssh.host');
 $username = config('ssh.username');
 $password = config('ssh.password'); 
 $command = 'php version';

 $ssh = new SSH2($host);
    if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
        $output ='Login Failed';
    }
    else{
        $output = $ssh->exec($command);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For today `pecl install ssh2` requires old versions of php (<=6.0). Here https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2 you can see the latest beta versions of ssh2 supporting php7 and php8. So you should install one of them:

```
pecl install ssh2-1.3.1
```

** Do not forget to enable this `ssh2.so` extension in your php.ini file.*

Answer (score 2):

I know there are answers but I am just simplifying the answer here.

I have same issue and I fixed it with below solution in ubuntu 20:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 php7.1-ssh2 -y
```

you can change the php version as per your need like: `php7.4-ssh2`

Ref: https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu-16-04-install-php-ssh2-extension

Answer (score 1):

**For WHM Panel**

Menu > Server Configuration > Terminal:

```
yum install libssh2-devel -y
```

Menu > Software > Module Installers

1. PHP PECL Manage Click
2. ssh2 Install Now Click

Menu > Restart Services > HTTP Server (Apache)

Are you sure you wish to restart this service?

Yes

**ssh2_connect() Work!**