# Execute a shell command through ssh using PHP

Tags: php, shell, ssh

I'm trying to execute a simple shell command and print the result on a web page but the results are empty. Below is one bit of code I found but nothing has worked thus far.

```
 <?php
            $server = "myserver";
            $username = "myadmin";
            $command = "ps";
            $str = "ssh " .$username. "@" .$server. " " .$command;

            exec($str, $output);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($output);
            echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the ssh command working by itself, meaning did you try it command line first?

Comment: `exec($str, $output, $return);`. Check the error code too, `var_dump(array($output, $return));`

Comment: also `echo $str;` get the string and try to run manually in shell.

Comment: @bjackfly Yes, the command is working by itself but not when used in the script

Comment: @Jigar There's no error code, its just that nothing is getting returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), that'll work.

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    $server = "myserver";
    $username = "myadmin";
    $password = "mypass";
    $command = "ps";

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
    if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    echo $ssh->exec($command);
?>
```

Comment: I can't install any packages on these machines. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Well, if you can create PHP source files on your machines, you can install phpseclib, because that's just a bunch of PHP files as well.

Comment: Is it possible to the login with SSH keys instead of using a hardcoded password?

Comment: Easily. Check out their [examples](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/new/ssh/examples.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly with the SSH key, too.

Comment: @ciruvan, can we user server ip instead of name ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `-p` option before the port number:

```
$str = "ssh -p $port $username@$server $command";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a more object oriented solution, you can install [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) version 2 with:

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
```

And then just create your ssh object:

```
$ssh = new SSH2('yourhost');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

In this exemple i have used a connection through *username* and *password* but you can also connect via ssh-keys.
If the connection is successful you can execute the method **exec** to execute you command on the server.