# Running remote python script from local PHP script

Tags: php, python, remote-server

I have two machines, 192.168.10.6 (local machine) which has my php script and 192.168.12.163 (remote machine) which has my python script. How can I run this remote python script from a local PHP script?

I have a working code for running local python script from a local PHP script but I'm not able run remote Python script from a local PHP script.

Comment: Can you ssh to the remote? You could use ssh to run a process on the remote: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-running-commands-on-a-remote-host.html

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to remote server but I want this to happen through PHP script calling python script located on a remote machine.

Comment: Do you mean you want the python script to be run at your local machine or at the remote machine?

Comment: @PavanR: Pemap has a point... if you need to run the (python) script on the local machine, you have to scp it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was about to propose using `shell_exec`/`exec` to spawn ssh and run a command on the remote host, for example:

```php
$out = shell_exec('ssh user@192.168.12.163 "ls -la"');
```

However, I see that PHP supports that with [`ssh2_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php), example:

```php
$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.12.163', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'python /path/to/script');
```

If ssh2 is not available on your server and you cannot install it, you can try [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373708/3727050) for example)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)

```
import paramiko, base64
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring('AAA...'))
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.get_host_keys().add('ssh.example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect('myRemoteMachine', username='strongbad', password='thecheat')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('python myScript.py')
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```