# SSH Connection to a remote server using PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I want to make a **SSH** connection to a remote server using php.

Im using php 5.3 on Linux/CEntOS.

What I have done so far :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.1.22', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, '_username', '_password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls -l');
```

But I'm getting this error :

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()**

So, my questions are :

1. Are `ssh2_*` functions not installed by default in php?
2. Do I need an extension or library for using these functions?
3. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function ssh2\_connect is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050231/php-function-ssh2-connect-is-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **phpseclib**

- Download it from [**here**](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) or  [**here**](http://break-point.ir/dl/phpseclib0.3.5.zip) ( direct link ) ,
- Include it to the project ,

And then :

```
   include('Net/SSH2.php');
   $ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
   $ssh->login('username', 'password') or die("Login failed");
   echo $ssh->exec('command');
```

Comment: suppose that you want to remotely execute an 'ls' command and bring the results to PHP....how do yo do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can configure your server (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: in ubuntu 16.04 the package to install is `php-ssh2`

Answer (score 3):

ssh_* function are not per default installed in php core.
You have to add them using pecl, see php manual for a good description: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php