# Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

Tags: php

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($SFTP_SERVER, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection,$SFTP_USERNAME,$SFTP_PASSWORD);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /var/www/html/beta/0sftp.php on line 33

my system is CentOS 6.4 all the required extensions is installed but I don't know how to verify.

Comment: Do you installed necessary libraries ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor ssh2_connect is PECL Extension function:: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Comment: Is the module enabled? Check `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @Sudhir, Not a built-in, It's a PECL Extension.

Comment: Not it's not built-in: It requires `(PECL ssh2 >= 0.9.0)`

Comment: try doing:: var_dump(extension_loaded('ssh2')); to check

Comment: Please refer this thread for good solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050231/php-function-ssh2-connect-is-not-working

Answer (score 9):

try to run the command :

> yum install php-pecl-ssh2

Comment: Or sudo aptitude install libssh2-php if you are under a debian-based.

Comment: For Debian 10 based distros, the package is php-ssh2. Installing, apt install php-ssh2

Answer (score 4):

For whatever it is worth, I tested the installation from the command line

```
php -i | grep ssh
```

and it was OK, but it did not work in a web page; took me a couple of minutes to remember I have to re-start Apache after installation :)