# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: php, ssh

Hey there here i am trying to run a php code to connect with SSH and i am using phpseclib but i am facing a very frustrating situation here.

```
$connection_string = ssh2_connect('xyz', 22);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function ssh2\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979144/call-to-undefined-function-ssh2-connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) and try commands below:

```
1. sudo apt install php-pear
2. sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
3. sudo sudo apt install phpуourversion-dev
4. sudo pecl install ssh2
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Not working for me.