# Connect to remote server using ssh in php

Tags: php, ssh, pecl

I want to connect to remote server and execute some commands. The server is running in Ubuntu and I am working on Windows. I am trying to implement ssh. But the connection is not working. Its my first time to work with ssh. I have searched a lot and after downloaded the required dll files from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2/1.1.1/windows) and added to `php/ext` path. Also enabled the dll in `php.ini` file. But the code is not working. It throws an error like `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()`

```
<?php 
  $connection = ssh2_connect('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 22);
 if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
?>
```

[image]

[image]

I have already added the extension in php.ini, but when I try to print the phpinfo(), it shows nothing about ssh2 extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function ssh2\_connect is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050231/php-function-ssh2-connect-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Moved `libssh2.dll` from `xampp/php` folder to `system32` and its working now